# Jquery fadeOut -> scroll -> fadeIn behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to achieve this thing on my ".list" element: list smoothly fades out, then scrollTop is changing, then it smoothly fades back in. I've checked several similar cases and seems like none of them actually helped me.

There is my code, what was the first thing that came to my mind.

```
    $(".list").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(".list").scrollTop(newPosition);
        $(".list").fadeIn(300);
    });
```

This piece do absolutly nothing but fades in and out. By searching the answers I've achieved somewhat close to my goal.

```
    $(".list").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(".list").fadeIn(300);
    }).delay(300).scrollTop(newPosition);
```

But still it seems like delay doesn't work at all here, and my list just changes scroll immediatly, then fades out and in.

I do realize that I probably can achieve this with `animate()`, but I've got pretty curious about what happening in my code.

Can someone explain this behavior? Is there is something special to `scrollTop()`, because this thing works exactly as I want

```
    $(".list").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(".list").text("something").fadeIn(300);
    });
```

while this doesn't work at all but fades out and in

```
    $(".list").fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(".list").scrollTop(newPosition).fadeIn(300);
    });
```

Edit:
Got it from guy in comments, thank you. `fadeOut()` sets list `display: none`.

`scrollTop()` of the element with `display: none` always 0, and once fading back in it returns to what it was before fading out. So I guess I should `animate()` the opacity instead and do my thing.

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing 300 to 3000 if the delay isn't apparent. the delay is in ms, so if you want it more pronounced, you need it to be 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: ofc while debuging a was changing numbers to bigger ones in order to clearly see the process. And it was just as I said in that case with `delay()`: I can see how list jumps changing scrollTop, then it fades out, then after argument in `delay()`, it fades in.

Comment: Are you sure your `newPosition` takes into account, that your list is faded out ? If u got a long list, and fade it out, your page "shrinks" and its possible that you can no longer scroll to the position u calculated

Comment: Oh that is actually right. `fadeIn()` sets `display: none` to the element. So I can't use scrollTop then. So is there a way to do that with jquery fades? Or i should use "animate()" and play with opacity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `scrollTop` of your body or html element (or another container), not your `.list` element
Here is a working example:

```js
$('.list').fadeOut(800, function(){
 $("html").animate({
   scrollTop: 180
  }, 800, function() {
   $('.list').fadeIn(800);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<ul class="list">
 <li>My List</li>
 <li>My List</li>
 <li>My List</li>
 <li>My List</li>
 <li>My List</li>
 <li>My List</li>
</ul>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: This is not my case. I probably should say that my ".list" - is a container with much content, capped height and hidden overflow. So clearly I don't need to scroll $(html). See this as some kind of slider.

Comment: Well then the answer is quite simple, u cant scroll an element with `display:none;` cause it has no position on your page.

Comment: There is no way to know "your case" because you didn't provide the markup for your problem. Add the markup to your post if you would like more useful assistance.